# SQLite : Return true if duplicate values are found in table

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

I want to know how you can find duplicate values in a table and make it return True. I have seen alot of questions about this but none of them helped, Thanks!

Here's my example :

```
import hashlib
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('users/accounts.db')
cur = con.cursor()
info = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts;").fetchall()

print("Sign Up.")
username = input("Input your username : ")
password = input("Input your password : ")
email = input("Input your email: ")

result = hashlib.sha256(password.encode("utf-8"))
result_2 = str(result.digest)

cur.execute("insert into accounts (username, password, email) values(?,?,?)", (username, result_2, email))

con.commit()
print(info)
con.close()
```

---

### Disclaimer

To those wondering, No this will not be used in a production environment, It is unsafe and can be easily exploited. Haven't even salted the hashes.

Comment: Can you add sample data which explains your problem?

Comment: added @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and expected results to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal be to prevent inserting a new user record with a username or email which already is being used by someone else, then an exists query provides one option:

```sql
INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email)
SELECT ?, ?, ?
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE username = ? OR email = ?);
```

That is, in a single statement we also can check if the username or email provided already appears somewhere in the `accounts` table.

Updated Python code:

```py
sql = """
    INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email)
    SELECT ?, ?, ?
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE username = ? OR email = ?)
"""
cur.execute(sql, (username, result_2, email, username, email))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have this table:

```
create table foo (
   foo_id numeric(12,0) primary key,
   str_value varchar(200)
);
```

And you want to find duplicate values for `str_value`.

You could do:

```
select str_value
  from foo
 group by str_value
having count(1) > 1;
```

You will have a list of `str_values` with dups on it.

If you want to know how many duplicates there are for each `str_value` you could add `count(1)` to your select clause:

```
select str_value, count(1)
  from foo
 group by str_value
having count(1) > 1;
```

Comment: Yeah, but how I return True if duplicates are found @Pablo Santa Cruz

Answer (score 0):

So this code worked

```
b = cur.execute("select * from accounts").fetchall()

sql = """INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email)
         SELECT ?, ?, ?
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM accounts WHERE username = ? OR email = ?)"""
cur.execute(sql, (username, str(result.digest()), email, username, email))

a = cur.execute("select * from accounts").fetchall()

if a > b:
    print("Registration Complete.")
else:
    print("Failed : Username or Email already exists.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).